# Extruding diagonal rectangle from interior corner

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am trying to model a small wooden crate like in [this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/93/34/17/9334175c8f58b6f0ec85738ea092dea3.png) image.

[image]

I am having trouble creating the diagonally extruded boards as I am trying to avoid adding new primitives and combining them later. I have gotten this far in the process.

[image: image here]

Can someone explain how to extrude the circled red corner and merge the extruded end to the other corner.

Thanks :)

Comment: Just as a matter of curiosity,  why the reluctant to add a new mesh, as opposed to extruding?

Comment: It will be far more efficient and logical to add that detail as separate mesh; in real life that plank is not continuation of the crate, it's separate object atop of it.

Comment: @MrZak I second that, also you will have less problem with UV/Texturing it and you can keep topology quad only without ngons/tris. You can always just join both meshes by Ctrl+J.

Comment: @brasshat
I am just trying to expand my knowledge of the program. I knew I could add the extra mesh but I wanted to know how to do it using the one mesh just so I could have the information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make 4 **Loop Cuts** (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) at where it should intersect.

[image: 1]

2. Select the 3 vertices IN THAT ORDER then press <kbd>J</kbd> to make a diagonal a line.

[image: 2]

3. Repeat step 2, but with opposite vertices, to create both diagonal lines.

[image: 3]

4. Select all 4 corners of the rectangle we have created.

[image: 4]

5. Press <kbd>E</kbd> and then whatever axis they are facing, then bring them out until they are flush with the outside rim of the box.

[image: 5]

6. Go into **Edge Select Mode**, then select these two edges, press <kbd>X</kbd>, then click **Delete Edges** .

[image: 6]

7. Select all the points and press <kbd>F</kbd> and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, to **Recalculate Normals**.

[image: 7]

8. DONE.

Let me know if thats not what you meant or if I messed up on a step!

Comment: It would be more useful to members of the BSE community if you would edit your answer to include a direct link to the images, as opposed to going through the link..

Comment: @brasshat he probably couldn't add so many images (low level user), I've added them for him.

Comment: @GoombaLover69 When I try to do the loop cuts they deform and don't remain straight lines. The vertices on the upper and lower edge move farther than the center edge and vertices. How do I keep them straight?